# Reading from UTF-16 encoded text file, þÿ is prepended on the front

Tags: java, file-io

I'm outputting a byte array to a text file using the following method:

```
try{
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath+".8102");
    fos.write(concatenatedIVCipherMAC);
    fos.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

which outputs to the file a UTF-16 encoded data, example:

> ¢¬6î)ªÈP~m˜LïiÆŸÃª•Àe»/#Ó ö¹¥‘þ²XhÃ&¼lG:Öé )GU3«´DÃ{+í—Ã]íò

However when I'm reading it back in I get `þÿ` prepended to the front of the data, e.g:

> þÿ¢¬6î)ªÈP~m˜LïiÆŸÃª•Àe»/?#Ó ö¹¥‘þ²XhÃ&¼lG:Öé )GU3«´DÃ{+í—Ã]íò

This is the method I'm using to read in the file:

```
private String getFilesContents()
{
    String fileContents = "";
    Scanner sc = null;

    try {
        sc = new Scanner(file, "UTF-16");
        System.out.println("Can read file: "+file.canRead());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        fileContents += sc.nextLine();                     
    }
    sc.close();
    return fileContents;
 }
```

and then `byte[] contentsOfFile = fileContents.getBytes("UTF-16");` to convert the String into a byte array.

A quick Google told me that þÿ represents the byte order but is it Java putting that there or Windows? How can I avoid having the þÿ prepended at the start of the data I'm reading in? I was thinking of just ignoring the first two bytes but if it is Windows then this will obviously break the program on other platforms.

edit: changed appended to prepended.

Comment: Um, that really doesn't look like *text* to start with. What is the file contents intended to *mean*? Are you sure it's not just a binary file?

Comment: @JonSkeet I've encrypted some data using AES-CBC. The file is the IV+data+MAC. It's not meant to be readable text? Should be I be doing something differently?

Comment: Why are you using Scanner to read the file? Scanner is for text files. Yours is a binary file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The file is the IV+data+MAC. It's not meant to be readable text? Should be I be doing something differently?

Yes. You shouldn't be trying to treat it as text *anywhere*.

If you really need to convert arbitrary binary data into text, use Base64 to convert it. Other than that, stick to byte arrays, `InputStream` and `OutputStream`.

I don't know exactly why you're supposedly getting extra characters, but the fact that you haven't got real text to start suggests that it's not really worth diagnosing that side. Just start handling binary data *as* binary data instead.

EDIT: Have a look at [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [IO helpers](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IOExplained) for simplicity...

Comment: Okay I'll use a FileInputStream instead of the Scanner then, I was just using that for simplicity's sake since I also use the method to read in an (actual) text file. ps. Kind of cool having you answer, read a lot about you!

Comment: @Peanut: See my edit - Guava can help you read a file simply.

Comment: I've used an InputStream and it seems to have improved the program's stability a lot! Didn't fix the prepending þÿ problem though but I think I isolated why... When I read in the plain text to be encrypted from a text file I use that Scanner method with UTF-16 in the question and then later plaintext.getBytes("UTF-16") to get the bytes to put into the Cipher. If I change both of these to UTF-8 then the þÿ isn't appended so something to do with that. Any idea why? I can just leave it as UTF-8, doesn't change the program.

Comment: @Peanut: Ideally, don't read it as text at all, if you just want to encrypt the bytes. But if you *are* going to read it as text, you need to read it in whatever the right encoding is. You shouldn't just pick one arbitrarily.

Comment: I just realised it would be to do with the text file encoding, changed from Scanner to InputStream and it works perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

`þÿ` is the [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) unicode character saved as UTF16-BE, interpreted as ISO-8859-1.

You shouldn't treat binary data as text (in whatever encoding), if you want to avoid such errors.