# What am I doing wrong loading a .txt file?

Tags: java, string, equals, bufferedreader

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Templates/format/test.txt")))
{

    String sCurrentLine;

    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(sCurrentLine.toString().trim());
        if(sCurrentLine.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Test2")){
            System.out.println("HI: "+sCurrentLine.toString().trim());
        }

    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm trying the get the contents of a .txt but neither

```
if(sCurrentLine.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Test2")){
    System.out.println("HI: "+sCurrentLine.toString().trim());
}
```

or

```
if(sCurrentLine.toString().trim().equals("Test2")){
    System.out.println("HI: "+sCurrentLine.toString().trim());
}
```

works.

This is the content of the txt:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```

I also don't understand why this: `System.out.println(sCurrentLine.toString().trim());` leads to the following output in the console. Why do I get breaks and the Symbol at the beginning?

```
þÿ T e s t 1
T e s t 2
T e s t 3
```

Thanks for helping me out here!

Comment: Looks like an encoding problem. Did you create the file or you are just trying to process it?

Comment: This is just a thought, is it possible that there is a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning ?

Comment: Sounds like an encoding problem, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748613/reading-from-utf-16-encoded-text-file-y-is-prepended-on-the-front

Comment: are you able to print the contents of file with first sysout inside while loop?

Comment: A minor issue that isn't causing your problem: Why call `toString()` on a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your .txt file to UTF-8 without BOM. You can do that with Notepad++ or any other advanced text editor.